# CSS - Trying to get content to scale down for smaller screens

Tags: html, css

[Codepen for my Card Game Project](https://codepen.io/mbert86/pen/LgoaYG)

Here is my CSS, and the rest of the code is in Codepen since its so long.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;


function flipCard() {
 if (lockBoard) return;
 if (this === firstCard) return;

 this.classList.add('flip');


if (!hasFlippedCard) {
 hasFlippedCard = true;
 firstCard = this;

 return;
}

secondCard = this;
checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
    let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

    isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
  }

  function disableCards() {
    firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
    secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

 resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
 lockBoard = true;

 setTimeout(() => {
  firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
  secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
  
  resetBoard();
 }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
 [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
 [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
 cards.forEach(card => {
  let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
  card.style.order = randomPos;
 });
})();


cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: "Courgette";
 font-size: 95px;
 padding-top: 35px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 840px;
  height: 840px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #1C7CCC;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Match The Leos</h1>

<section class="memory-game">
  
 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow1">
<img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/hQQx7f/leo1.jpg" alt="leo1" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
  
  <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow1">
<img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/hQQx7f/leo1.jpg" alt="leo1" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
  
  <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow2">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/fOjqSf/leo2.jpg" alt="leo2" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow2">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/fOjqSf/leo2.jpg" alt="leo2" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
  
  <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow3">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ezcYf0/leo3.jpg" alt="leo3" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow3">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ezcYf0/leo3.jpg" alt="leo3" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
  
  <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow3">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/mBVm00/leo4.jpg" alt="leo4" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow3">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/mBVm00/leo4.jpg" alt="leo4" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
  
  <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow5">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/hFcoDL/leo5.jpg" alt="leo5" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow5">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/hFcoDL/leo5.jpg" alt="leo5" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow6">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/d9FatL/leo6.jpg" alt="leo6" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>

 <div class="memory-card" data-framework="meow6">
  <img class="front-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/d9FatL/leo6.jpg" alt="leo6" border="0">
  <img class="back-face" src="https://image.ibb.co/ef2oDL/cardback.jpg" alt="cardback" border="0">
 </div>
</section>
</div>
```

I am making a card matching game, and I have everything almost how I need it, but I am struggling with some CSS on this.

I am trying to figure out how to get the section of the game to scale down as the screen/browser becomes smaller. I have been messing with CSS all afternoon and I still am struggling with this last piece. any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'd suggest doing a bit more googling. You'll probably notice all the UI frameworks are switching to other units of measurement like REM & EM [for a reason](https://medium.com/@julienetienne/pixels-are-dead-faa87cd8c8b9). Cheers!

Comment: What about the Bootstrap library? Their row and column stuff is pretty much built for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Pen](https://codepen.io/DanStevens/pen/QZXLWd) I've branched from yours.

I've brought in a widely used responsive framework called [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to help break your cards into a grid layout that adjusts to the user's viewport. In addition I've written a few custom rules with [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). With media queries you can write styles that are specific to a given viewport width (or height).

Hopefully this is enough to get you thinking about how using a responsive framework can help style content for all kinds of screen dimensions.

Example of the columns within a bootstrap "row":

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-3">
```

Example of a media query with rules for screens 768 pixels and wider:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .your-rule-here {
 }
}
```